# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.builder()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet$Builder

Tags: guava, wildfly-10, immutable-collections

I'm getting this error continuously

```
Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.builder()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet$Builder;
```

[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.builder()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet$Builder;"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./"],"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined}}}

And here is what I have in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-multibindings</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for this.
Checked all the dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree`

[image]

And then found that `org.drools` library is there and it is containing `google-collections` associated with that. But now `google-collections` is deprecated, we can get the same by using `com.google.guava`.
So excluded the `google-collections` from drools dependency, So it worked for me.
Added this into the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.drools</groupId>
<artifactId>drools-ant</artifactId>
<version>5.1.1</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```